# Swift - Display header with animation

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm kinda new to Swift coding and I wanted to train myself by finding some layouts and try to implement them using AutoLayout.

Here is a screen shot of a screen I try to implement

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PZXr.png

The behaviour is wanted here is that on scrolling the picture should fade away and the title should be set like so

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhA9w.png

Could anybody help me on how am I supposed to do that ?
Should I use a ScrollView ? UITableView ? UICollectionView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually working on an application that does something similar.

[image]

So, the first thing you want to do is create a `UIView` for the background, i.e. the blue part that shows Squirtle. This view can take up the entire view controller. Connect it to your `UIViewController` via `IBOutlet` and call it `backgroundView`.

Next, we want to lay a `UIScrollView` over `backgroundView`. This scroll view should be constrained to the top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges of the superview so that it covers the entire view controller's frame. Connect this `UIScrollView` to your `UIViewController` via `IBOutlet` and name it `scrollView`. Also, make sure that `scrollView`'s `backgroundColor` is set to `clear`. This way, we'll be able to see `backgroundView` underneath our `scrollView`.

Within your `UIViewController`, you'll want to set `scrollView`'s delegate to `self` inside of `viewDidLoad`. Your `UIViewController`'s code should now look something like this:

```
class SquirtleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension SquirtleViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

}
```

We'll set delegate methods for `scrollView` later. These will help us know when the scroll view has begun scrolling to the top of our `SquirtleViewController`.

Now, our `scrollView` has a clear background, and doesn't actually display anything to our user. This is how we want it for now. We want the top of our `scrollView` to be clear so that we can see `backgroundView` behind it, and the bottom of our `scrollView` to have another view, i.e. the "content view" that shows `STATS`, `EVOLUTIONS`, `MOVES`, `HP`, etc.

So, let's add another `UIView` as a subview of our `scrollView`. Connect it to `SquirtleViewController` via `IBOutlet` and name it `contentView`.

Now, we need to create a constraint between `contentView`'s top edge and `scrollView`'s top edge. This constraint's constant needs to be equal to the height of `backgroundView`'s content. This way, our `contentView` won't cover up what we want to see from `backgroundView`. We should also save this height as `backgroundViewContentHeight` so that we can reference it later.

We also need `contentView`'s `leading`, `trailing`, and `bottom` constraints to be equal to those of its superview, i.e. `scrollView`. These do not need to be connected via `IBOutlet`s.

Also, give `contentView` a `height` and `width` constraint and connect these as `contentViewHeight` and `contentViewWidth` respectively to `SquirtleViewController` via `IBOutlet`. This will help us set the `contentSize` of our `scrollView` later.

Your code should now look something like this:

```
class SquirtleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    //New lines of code
    //Our constraints
    @IBOutlet var contentViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var backgroundViewContentHeight = 400

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension SquirtleViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

}
```

Now, when `SquirtleViewController` lays out its subviews, we are going to want to set the `constant` properties of `contentViewHeight` and `contentViewWidth`. This will set a `contentSize` for our `scrollView`. We want our `contentViewWidth` to simply be the size of our `SquirtleViewController`'s `view`'s width. Our `contentViewHeight`'s `constant` will be a little different though, as it depends on the height of our `contentView`'s subviews. For this example, we'll say the `contentViewHeight`'s `constant` should be 1200. The code should now look like this:

```
class SquirtleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    //Our constraints
    @IBOutlet var contentViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var backgroundViewContentHeight = 400

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    //New lines of code
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        contentViewWidth.constant = view.frame.width
        contentViewHeight.constant = 1200
    }
}

extension SquirtleViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

}
```

From here, you can add subviews to `backgroundView` and `contentView` as you see fit in order to show the pokemon (`backgroundView`) as well as the pokemon's stats (`contentView`). But, you still need to know how to change the content of your `backgroundView` depending upon how much we have scrolled the `scrollView`. This is where the `UIScrollViewDelegate` helps us out.

There is a method in `UIScrollViewDelegate` that is called every time our `scrollView`'s `contentOffset.y` changes. This basically means every time we change the amount that our `scrollView` has scrolled, this method will be called.

Inside of this method, we can cross reference the amount we've scrolled with the height of the background view. As our `scrollView`'s `contentOffset.y` approaches the height of our `backgroundView`'s content, we can fade out the image of Squirtle and fade in a `UILabel` that simply says "Squirtle" (like in your example).

So, in your case, I would suggest adding a `UIImage` of Squirtle as a subview of `contentView` and connect it via `IBOutlet` as `pokemonImageView`. `pokemonImageView` should have its frame partially outside of the `contentView` (like in your example). If you do this, ensure that `contentView`'s `clipsToBounds` property is set to `false`.

I would also add a `UILabel` as a subview of `backgroundView` and connect it to `SquirtleViewController` via `IBOutlet` as `pokemonNameLabel`. When our `SquirtleViewController`'s view loads, we should set `pokemonNameLabel.alpha` equal to zero so that it is initially hidden.

Your code should now look like this:

```
class SquirtleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!

    //New line of code
    @IBOutlet var pokemonNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    //New line of code
    @IBOutlet var pokemonImageView: UIImageView!

    //Our constraints
    @IBOutlet var contentViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var backgroundViewContentHeight = 400

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        //New line of code
        pokemonNameLabel.alpha = 0
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        contentViewWidth.constant = view.frame.width
        contentViewHeight.constant = 1200
    }
}

extension SquirtleViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

}
```

Now we simply need to add the `scrollViewDidScroll` method inside of our class extension. This is the method that will tell us our `scrollView`'s `contentOffset.y` property so that we know how much we've scrolled. As this number increases, our `pokemonImageView`'s alpha should decrease to zero and our `pokemonNameLabel`'s alpha should increase towards one.

Inside of this method, I would divide our `scrollView.contentOffset.y` by the height of our `backgroundView` minus the height of the `pokemonNameLabel`. We can then use this decimal to set our respective alphas of `pokemonImageView` and `pokemonNameLabel`.

Your code should now look something like this:

```
class SquirtleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!

    //New line of code
    @IBOutlet var pokemonNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    //New line of code
    @IBOutlet var pokemonImageView: UIImageView!

    //Our constraints
    @IBOutlet var contentViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var contentViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var backgroundViewContentHeight = 400

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        //New line of code
        pokemonNameLabel.alpha = 0
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        contentViewWidth.constant = view.frame.width
        contentViewHeight.constant = 1200
    }
}

extension SquirtleViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //Subtracting contentView.frame.height from scrollView.frame.height
        let alphaDecimal = scrollView.contentOffset.y / (backgroundViewContentHeight - pokemonNameLabel.frame.height)
        pokemonNameLabel.alpha = alphaDecimal
        pokemonImageView.alpha = 1 - alphaDecimal
    }
}
```

Now, as we scroll up and what can be seen of the `backgroundView` shrinks, our `pokemonImageView` will fade out and our `pokemonNameLabel` will fade in. There will be a point in-between where both will have an alpha of 0.5. You can mess with this `scrollViewDidScroll` method as you see fit to make this work best for you.

Comment: @ImadBenAbdeslam lemme know how it goes. I know there was a lot to it, i tried to make it as clear as possible